# How to save data from Entry Widget in list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, user-interface, tkinter

The idea behind this part of my program is that the user must enter a username, after which the name will be saved in the "Individuals" list. I tried to make sure that the names entered by the user are saved in the "Individuals" list. However, I get an error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "main.py", line 45, in confirm
    users.append(Individuals)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I would really like to know how is it possible to save names from entry widget in the list.

My code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class CollegeApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        container = ttk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (IndividPage,):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(IndividPage)
        self.lift()

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class IndividPage(ttk.Frame):


    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.userEntry()

    def userEntry(self):
        headingTest = Label(self, text="Enter your UserName:", font="Arial 20")
        headingTest.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5, padx=5)

        self.usernameEnter = Entry(self, width=40)
        self.usernameEnter.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

        confirmBtn = Button(self, text="Confirm User", font="Arial 16",
                            command=self.confirm)

        confirmBtn.config(height=4, width=12)
        confirmBtn.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=E, padx=45, pady=360)

    def confirm(self):
        users = self.usernameEnter.get()
        users.append(Individuals)
        print(Individuals)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Individuals = []
    app = CollegeApp()
    app.geometry("800x500")
    app.title('Points Counter')
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to append a list to a string, rather than a string to a list. The code needs to be this:

```
Individuals.append(users)
```